# Bonjour NSNetServiceBrowser in iOS6 Not working

Tags: iphone, ios6, bonjour

I'm working on advertising a desktop client to phones on the local network. My phone is at 6.0.2 with the Xcode 4.5.2.

I know the desktop app is registering successfully because the Discovery app ([by Tildesoft](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)) on my phone shows my service on the network (which also rules out wifi problems).

I've downloaded the Apple app example, [Bonjour Web](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html). The delegate for finding "_myservice._tcp" didn't ever fire, but the start browsing method does fire.

I tried using [HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices) (which wraps DNSService), and while the start browsing method fired, the service found method doesn't fire.

**In my own app**, I tried using NSNetServiceBrowser. I set the delegate, and my "netServiceBrowserWillSearch" delegate method gets fired, but nothing else happens.

Code is attached if you want to verify.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ClientFinder_ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *availableClientsTableView;


-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindDomain:(NSString *)domainString moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing;
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing;
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didNotSearch:(NSDictionary *)errorDict;
-(void)netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser;
-(void)netServiceBrowserWillSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser;

@end
```

Relevant Implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dictionaryFoundClients = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [self addLogoToNabar];
    [self listen];
}

-(void)listen{
    NSNetServiceBrowser *serviceBrowser = [NSNetServiceBrowser new];
    [serviceBrowser setDelegate:self];
    [self.netServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:TYPE inDomain:domain];
}


-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindDomain:(NSString *)domainString moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing{
    NSLog(@"aNetServiceBrowser didFindDomain");
}


-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing{
    NSLog(@"aNetServiceBrowser didFindService");
    [dictionaryFoundClients setObject:aNetService forKey:aNetService.hostName];
    NSLog(@"Found service: %@ @ %@", aNetService.name, aNetService.hostName);
}

-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didNotSearch:(NSDictionary *)errorDict{
    NSLog(@"aNetServiceBrowser didNotSearch. Errors enumerated");
    for(int a=0; a< errorDict.count; a++){
        NSString *key = [[errorDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:a];
        NSString *val = [errorDict objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, val);
    }
}

-(void)netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser{
    NSLog(@"netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch");
}

-(void)netServiceBrowserWillSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser{
    NSLog(@"netServiceBrowserWillSearch");
}
```

Comment: This looks like similar to other thread and my answer is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17259893/1850244

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it started working, but here is my working code:

```
    [self stopCurrentResolve];
    [self.netServiceBrowser stop];
    [self.services removeAllObjects];

    NSNetServiceBrowser *aNetServiceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
    if(!aNetServiceBrowser) {
        // The NSNetServiceBrowser couldn't be allocated and initialized.
        return NO;
    }

    aNetServiceBrowser.delegate = self;
    self.netServiceBrowser = aNetServiceBrowser;
    [self.netServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:type inDomain:domain];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is all local, you need to use searchForServicesOfType: method instead of searchForRegistrationDomains method.

```
-(void)listen{
  NSNetServiceBrowser *serviceBrowser = [NSNetServiceBrowser new];
  [serviceBrowser setDelegate:self];
  [serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_your_service_type._tcp" inDomain:@""];;
}
```

"_your_service_type._tcp" is the service type your desktop application is using when it advertises its service.

Comment: I apologize, before I posted by code, I was trying to get NSNetServiceBrowser to do *anything*. I'll edit my question. I actually have an answer to it now.